# What is the best way to serve a user generated graph on a website using django

Tags: python, django

Currently I have a code that generates a sine graph but it is coded such that it draws and saves the image to the static folder to be retrieved. Since I am trying to make the graph generation based on user request, is there a way it can do that without the graph being saved.

Comment: Depends on the library you're using to generate the graph. Can you provide that information? Also, is there a reason why you have to do the graph generation on the server if it's always generated for each user request? There are a number of good Javascript graphing libraries that should be able to generate what you're looking for in-browser.

Comment: Here is an example of a function plotter using an HTML5 canvas. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-graphing-an-equation/

Comment: @bmhkim I am using matplotlib and PIL. Its generally a program which does some calculations and outputs a graph as it is more useful and interactive to the user. I am not familiar with Javascript graphing libraries, will it be tough to incorporate them into django?

Comment: @bmhkim Thanks for the link but I prefer to have my calculations to be in the django framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return an image as an HTTP response. Just make sure to set the correct MIME type.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_image(request):
    image_data = some_plotting_or_whatever()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

However, this means doing some_plotting_or_whatever on every request which may not be good for your performance. Serving relatively large files through django is not ideal for performance too. Saving your images to a file to be served directly by the web server may be a simple and quite efficient way to go.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/benoitbryon/django-downloadview to offload the image serving to your webserver using the sendfile protocol.

Comment: @sbarzowki I manage to get the image out but how can I close the picture without clicking the back button. A crude example would be clicking the black borders closes the picture much like viewing each photo in facebook.

Comment: @Smeaton Its a little advance for me, thanks for the suggestion anyway, I'll have a look at it in the future.

Comment: @Eugene This is just an image. If you want to have something more you can make an html page and use the image just as you would use the static one i.e. with <img src="my_image_url">.

Comment: @sbarzowski I can do that too but how do I make it dynamic? In a sense that only generate the image upon user request. E.g. first user on webpage, no image, upon request generates and shows image, now second user logs in image already generate hence shows image.

Comment: @Eugene If I understand correctly, this is a matter of application logic. You can generate, (optionally) save and show your image whenever you want.  Anytime your user makes an http request you can do something with it, like for example generate an image. Wanna do it when button is clicked? No problem. When specific page is requested? No problem. Then when user requests a page which should contain the image just use <img> tag. The url in <img> can be handled in static or dynamic or whatever way. Maybe more context, please...

Answer (score 0):

I have used ipython notebooks premade with dynamic content, execute them, convert to HTML and post the content as a webpage (all automated). Also check out [jakevdp blog](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/01/10/d3-plugins-truly-interactive/)